# How to get a hashtable in PowerShell from a multiline string in which keys and values are on different lines?

Tags: string, powershell, split, hashtable, text-parsing

I have a string of the following format (the number of lines in this string may vary):

```powershell
$content = @"
key1
value1
key2
value2
key3
value3
"@
```

I want to put this data in a hashtable.

(In my case, the data in the `$content` variable is received in the body of the HTTP response from the [Invoke-WebRequest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest) cmdlet by [Client/Server Protocol](https://stat.livejournal.com/doc/server/ljp.csp.guide.intro.html) in the '[LiveJournal](https://www.livejournal.com/)'. But I am interested in the answer to my question for the general case as well.)

I tried to use the cmdlet [ConvertFrom-StringData](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-stringdata), but it doesn't work for this case:

```
PS C:\> ConvertFrom-StringData -StringData $content -Delimiter "`n"
ConvertFrom-StringData: Data line 'key1' is not in 'name=value' format.
```

I wrote the following function:

```powershell
function toHash($str) {
  $arr = $str -split '\r?\n'
  $hash = @{}
  for ($i = 0; $i -le ($arr.Length - 1); $i += 2) {
    $hash[$arr[$i]] = $arr[$i + 1]
  }
  return $hash
}
```

This function works well:

```
PS C:\> toHash($content)

Name                           Value
----                           -----
key3                           value3
key2                           value2
key1                           value1
```

**My question is**: is it possible to do the same thing, but shorter or more elegant? Preferably in *one-liner* ([see the definition of this term](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/ps101/04-pipelines) in the book 'PowerShell 101'). Maybe there is a convenient regular expression for this case?

Comment: The code you already have looks elegant to me, shorter != more elegant

Comment: `$i -le ($arr.Length - 1)` can be `$i -lt $arr.Length` tho

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon Thanks for the correction in the cycle condition, I'll take it into account.

Comment: for the PowerShell golfing, how about: `foreach ($key in -split $content) { @{$key = if($foreach.MoveNext()){$foreach.Current}} }`

Comment: @AbrahamZinala thats pretty clever, worth an answer for sure ;) but instead of `@{$key =  if(.....)` you would need `$hash[$key] = if(.....)` else it would be an array of hashes instead of a single hash

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon, because of that caveat I didn't post one lol I originally had this: `foreach ($key in $(-split $content;$ht=@{})) { $ht[$key]=if($foreach.MoveNext()){$foreach.Current} }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As commented by @Santiago Squarzon;

> The code you already have looks elegant to me, **shorter `-ne` more elegant**

For the "*Preferably in one-liner*", what exactly is definition of a one line:

- A single line, meaning a text string with no linefeeds?
- Or a single statement meaning a text string with no linefeeds *and* no semicolons?
  Knowing that there are several ways to cheat on this, like assigning a variable in a condition (which is hard to read).

**Anyways, a few side notes:**
The snippet you show might have a pitfall if you have an odd number of lines and [`Set-StrictMode -Version Lastest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/set-strictmode) enabled:

```
Set-StrictMode -Version Latest
toHash "key1`nvalue1`nkey2"
OperationStopped:
Line |
   5 |      $hash[$arr[$i]] = $arr[$i + 1]
     |      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | Index was outside the bounds of the array.

Name                           Value
----                           -----
key1                           value1
```

The variable neme `$content`, suggests that you reading the data from a file, possibly with [`Get-Connent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content). If that is indeed the case you might consider to stream the input (which conserves memory):

```
$Content -split '\r?\n' | # Get-Content .\Data.txt
Foreach-Object -Begin {
    $Hash = @{}
    $Key = $Null
} -Process { 
    if (!$Key) {
        $Key = $_
    }
    else {
        $Hash[$Key] = $_
        $Key = $Null
    }
} -End {
    $Hash
}
```

And if you create use an `[ordered]` dictionary, you might even put this is a single statement like:

```
$Content -split '\r?\n' |Foreach-Object { $h = [Ordered]@{} } { if (!$h.count -or $h[-1]) { $h[$_] = $Null } else { $h[$h.Count - 1] = $_ } } { $h }
```

<sub>(Note that -as with the propose in the question- I do not take into account that there might be empty lines in the input data)</sub>

See also PowerShell issue: [`#13817` Enhance hash table syntax](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/13817)

Comment: Under the term 'one-liner' I was referring to the definition from the book 'PowerShell 101' ([Chapter 4 - One-liners and the pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/ps101/04-pipelines)). I thought it was a well-known term (I'm new to PowerShell).

Comment: The `$content` variable for me implies the body of the HTTP response received from the [Invoke-WebRequest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest) cmdlet. This is the HTTP response by [Client/Server Protocol](https://stat.livejournal.com/doc/server/ljp.csp.guide.intro.html) in the '[LiveJournal](https://www.livejournal.com/)'.